# How to make two projects with incompatible .NET versions talk?

Tags: c#, .net

I know that I can't be the only one with this problem but my googling simply hasn't provided anything fruitful. I may be missing some key word. Anyway, here's the issue:

We are developing a C# program that utilizes a third party backend. We can't substitute this backend for something else, no matter what.

The API for this backend is provided by the backend manufacturer in the form of two DLLs and is currently built on .NET Framework 4.6.1 and will soon be upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8. In a year or two it most likely uses something else as 4.8 is the last version of .NET Framework.

Most of our program is about a lot of other stuff that we would love to be able to code with something newer than .NET Framework 4.8, e.g., .NET 6 or 8.

So now my question is, how can we have a Visual Studio solution with different projects where one targets .NET Framework 4.8 and others target .NET 6, say?

(Imagine a car manufacturer without a factory trying to automate the complete car design process in .NET 8.0 but ultimately having to ask some external factory that only speaks .NET Framework 4.8 to build the car.)

I have previously had solutions with a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project and a .NET Standard 2.0 project, but these are compatible. What if I have two incompatible versions of .NET? I'm hoping that there is some sort of go-to architecture or design pattern that can be used here. I'm guessing it can be done by some sort of microservice architecture but I don't know how these would then best talk to each other...

Comment: the target framework is project specific, and a solution with multiple projects on different target frameworks: is absolutely fine and just works; are you hitting a specific problem? note that if you have library projects that are needed by incompatible projects, you *can* use netstandard, but it is usually easier to multi-target the library, i.e. `<TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>` or similar

Comment: By "the API of that Backend" you mean an ApiClient Project? Is that provided by the backend manufacturer? In what form? Nuget? A dll? Source code? Just specification?

Comment: The API is provided by the backend manufacturer in the form of two DLLs that I simply reference and use.

Comment: I haven't tried multi-targeting. Would that allow a net8.0 project to reference a net48 project directly? I'm guessing that the multi-targeting would only be required in the other projects referencing the net48 backend api, correct?

Comment: I don't think multitargetting will help if your dlls are targeting a specific runtime already. If you had their source code, you could try that but not with only the dlls.

Comment: @ThomasRavkilde No it won't. You get multiple output assemblies build for the named target frameworks. It isn't a bridge between incompatible frameworks. You need an API with a broader scope to be reusable. You may create one via creating a process hosting that 3rd party assembly and resurfacing its functionality in a proper way like Http/REST and then use that in the actual processes needing that.

Comment: Yes, that's also what I thought. There's no chance of getting the source code, unfortunately.
I just updated my question slightly. Hopefully, it is now a bit clearer what I'm asking.

Comment: You still should rethink if binding to that 3rd party is a sustainable thing if they are living in "ancient" technology.

Comment: ^^ being locked-in to _anything_ 3rd party is a risk you need to consider carefully.

Comment: @Ralf Thanks. Hiding behind http/REST was one of my thoughts as well but I was hoping for something easier and more plug-ad-play... ;) That 3rd party is our bread and butter and there's no way we will be allowed to use something else. They're a huge company in a field of slow turnover due to regulations (health). That's why they're living in "ancient" tech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are lucky you can just use the .net framework libraries in .net 5+ projects directly. Some APIs have been removed between .Net 4.8 and .Net 5, and if these APIs are used you will get runtime errors, and because of this Visual studio will complain. But it should be fairly easy to test, and may work just fine.

Also note that you can code in the latest c# version in a .net framwork project by using a [`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) tag in the project file. This will only work for "syntactic suggar" stuff that do not need runtime changes. But such syntactic suggar still helps development a fair bit.

The universal solution is to run the different .net projects in different processes, and use your favorite type of Inter Process Communication (IPC) method to handle calls. There are many such methods to chose from but you could start by checking out [gRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC). Do note that this approach will mean a decent amount of overhead in development, since any calls need to go trough an extra communication layer.

Comment: Thanks! Very good tips. I'm hoping that the amount of overhead creating an extra communication layer is less than what we would have developing in older frameworks and constantly having to update everything to match new versions of our supplier. Also, I guess it actually opens up the possibility of changing the supplier...

Comment: @ThomasRavkilde If it is *worth the effort* is a very difficult judgment, that you are in the best position to answer. Do note that different suppliers often have significantly different APIs, so if switching suppliers is a goal you should look at other suppliers APIs to try to avoid a "Leaky abstraction".

Answer (score 3):

### Process isolation

A third party DLL that uses a framework that is out-of-step with your organization's norms should be isolated to its own process when possible. This process should run under its own application identity adhering to a standard of least privilege. This reduces the blast radius if (heaven forbid) the third party has quality issues or vulnerabilities in their software.

One approach would be for your organization to write a thin RESTful wrapper for the DLLs that runs as a web service in its own application domain. The rest of your enterprise software would merely call the RESTful interface. The DLLs need only be deployed to the single web server. From there you can apply patches and upgrades from the third party on whatever their backwater schedule may be.